# unity3d: Animator bug or feature?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, animator

I'm having a conflict between animator and image.

[Step 1: Before running unity: sprite = null and animator disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tahv5.png)

Step 2: Running unity: I'm changing sprite to 12.png and animator disabled

[Step 3: Enabled animator and sprite changed to null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vf4J.png)

Question: why animator returns to the sprite that was before unity running?
Even if on step 1 image has some other sprite (different from null), on step 3 animator returns to that sprite.
While animator component is enable I can't change sprite.
P.S. Animation is blank in the animator.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a sprite in the animation assigned to the default animator state?

Comment: "Writes Default" = true if it's what you mean.

Comment: Here is an example of my problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ceq1fs6urzq7g9m/ExampleAnimatorBug.unitypackage?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Any thing you do while unity is playing a scene will be reset to its original state when you stop playing it. Consider doing it while unity is not playing if you want to persist changes while playing unity. The following resourse may help

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/612572/is-it-possible-to-save-changes-made-in-editor-in-p.html

Comment: I don't want save changes in runtime.
I want to change image when animator is enabled.
For example: 
I have 2 sprites (1.png and 2.png) and rectTransform object on the scene with animator and image components on it.
Before playing a scene image.sprite = 1.png and animator is disable.
When a scene is running, I change image.sprite = 2.png.
But when animator is changed to enable, image.sprite return to value 1.png automatically and change a sprite is impossible while animator is enabled.
Default animation is empty.


What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently and neither did I solve it there's a unity official video about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1401&v=rMCLWt1DuqI).

But in my scenario it didn't help. So I decided to create different animations and control them with animator parameters.

Good luck.